# Is the RAII supported?

Tags: c++, raii

Last time I see some video where Mr. Stroustrup talking about RAII in C++. I wanted to know more and found this page:

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/MEM44-CPP.+Do+not+leak+resources+when+handling+exceptions

Is this MEM44-CPP just a proposal to the next specification of C++ or is it already available? How do I know my compilation tools supports RAII?

Comment: RAII is *paramount* to C++. Any C++ compiler that does not respect it is definitely not a C++ compiler.

Comment: C++ supports RAII as a language intrinsic feature.

Comment: RAII isn't a specific language feature. It's a technique based on destructors, which have always been a part of C++.

Comment: I wrote a bit on resource management including RAII in different programming language [here](http://lazarenko.me/2013/03/03/automatic-resource-management/). You will (hopefully) find it useful.

Comment: @BoBTFish. This technique must be recognized by the compiler somehow. If you consider some C++ tools on less popular architectures (ARM, MIPS), can I still be sure RAII is supported?

Comment: I have never heard of a C++ compiler that did not support destructors. They are an absolutely fundamental part of the language, which have been there right from the earliest days. If they are not supported it is **not** a C++ compiler.

Comment: @BoBTFish There's "supported" and "reliably supported".  Every C++ compiler I've used has allowed you to define destructors, but some of the early ones could be very lax about calling them: g++ 1.49 skipped the destructors of local variables if you left the function via a `return`, for example, and a couple of early compilers would sometimes call them on temporaries or variables which had never been constructed.  In recent years, the only problems I've encountered have been with VC++, however (and that bug was fixed in VC++2010).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RAII is a design pattern, based on the fact that the destructor is
called whenever the scope of an object is left, and this,
regardless of the reason for leaving the scope.  As design
patterns go, it's use is limited to languages which have 
destructors which are called whenever the scope of an object is
left: C++ and (I think) Ada 95, although there may be others.

As it is a design pattern, it has nothing to do with the
compiler, *except* that it necessitates having destructors
called at the right time.  This has been a feature of the C++
language since the very earliest days, although early compilers
often got it wrong.  The last compiler I'm aware of which had
problems in this respect, however, was the C++ in Visual Studios
2008 (which sometimes failed to call destructors it should
have).  Most other compilers have been fine since the mid
1990's.

Comment: I thought the fact that destructor is called after leaving scope is because of RAII 'support', but this is just a plain C++. Thanks, its clear now.

Comment: In some ways the two are linked.  Destructors were probably introduced in order to support RAII, although it wasn't called that yet, and the full power of RAII hadn't been realized.  But long before the name RAII was being bandied about, destructors were being used for other things as well.

Answer (score 9):

RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) is something inherent to C++, or rather something that can be used to alleviate memory handling issues when applied correctly, by *you*.

Every C++ compiler "supports" RAII.

Comment: Any kind of resource that must conceptually be acquired/released, not just memory.

Comment: @rubenvb. If you consider some C++ tools on less popular architectures (ARM, MIPS), can I still be sure RAII is supported?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this answer: RAII has nothing to do with C++, per se; it can be used with any language which has destructors.  It's more along the lines of a design pattern.

Comment: @flyer All that RAII requires is destructors which are reliably called.  And destructors have been present in C++ since the very beginning.  About the only recent compiler which didn't support it was the ones in Visual Studios, 2008 and before, and even then, only in a few very special cases (which you wouldn't want in cleanly written code anyway).

Comment: @JamesKanze Can it not still be inherent (albeit not exclusively) to C++ ? Say, the will to power might be inherent to human nature, but that doesn't preclude it from being inherent to Martian nature as well.

Comment: @us2012 In this case, the concept is rather independent of the language, I think.  The question isn't whether some compiler supports (or doesn't support) RAII; it's whether the compiler supports (without bugs) destructors.  (Which are useful for other things as well.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh! I thought your criticism was that this answer somehow made it seem like RAII was exclusive to C++. I get your point now.